# How do I load only a single wordpress post via the url?

Tags: wordpress

We are currently undergoing some reworking of our website - in the meantime, I am looking for a quick a dirty fix.

We have wordpress setup, so that no-so-tech-savvy employees can add events, news, etc. However, there are currently sections on our site dedicated to what would be tags in Wordpress.

For instance, we have posts in WP with the tag "events." It's easy enough to display all posts with that tag, but I need to do a PHP include on our old site, and only show JUST THE POST. I can use a rss2html tool, but it strips out somethings like necessary tables.

So how do Display only a single WP post, without anything else (no menus, settings, no Wp interface) via a URL? I could use a theme that is stripped down (by using something like theme switcher), but I need it to only load that theme once, not be the default theme....

Comment: Does this "simple view" have to be outside the /wordpress/ hierarchy? Based on your question it's not clear if the whole site is managed with WordPress or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Query-based_Templates

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty way: select post_content from wp_posts where ID= [yourpostid]
   and if you need some special queries e.g. meta data: just check the database diagram: http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP_27_dbsERD.png